# SharePoint 2010 discussion board item link in workflow

Tags: designer-workflow, email, hyperlink, discussion-board

I am trying to create a designer workflow in SharePoint 2010 for a discussion board. I am sending out email to the users associated to that discussion when ever an item is created/changed. Now i am struck with on how to configure the hyperlink for the discussion board item to make users to click on the hyperlink so that they would be directed to the discussion. Can some one help me out this scenario. `<a href="https://testsite/subsite/lists/discussionboard/flat.aspx"RootFolder=`

[image: I am unable to figure out what needs to go in here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `URLPath` to get the RootFolder as below

[image]

Comment: Hi Amal I have already tried that but it takes me to the discussion board list not to the item where the discussion is created.

Comment: I tried it before I posted.. Working fine in my case

Comment: I did not get it..you mean i need to add that in the source field? foldername

Comment: I mean if you are getting `http://site/lists/discussion` from `URL Path` then you add the missing foldername which is the Title field value.. so the full expression will be like `[%Current Item:URL Path%]/[%Current Item:Title%]` ... I am giving Title as an example, you can try different fields till you form the proper URL

Comment: Hi Amal I tried to add the current item:title but no luck...this is the url which the item is existing https://spsite.beta.com/CED/Lists/WesternCOC/Flat.aspx?RootFolder=%2FCED%2FLists%2FWesternCOC%2Fwesttest&FolderCTID=0x01200200E3B2358B0750654CBF9F3EA96F787021 and with the string which I am passing I am getting this https://spsite.beta.com/CED/Lists/WesternCOC/Flat.aspx?RootFolder=/CED/Lists/WesternCOC/westtest

Comment: Hi Amal..after trial and error I could figure out what should be there after  URL Path and it worked. Thanks again for your suggestion.